# Why doesn't downloading text file work correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.3.1. I have created a function called `download_file()` which downloads the file and saves it to disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import datetime
import os
import urllib.error
import urllib.request


def download_file(*urls, download_location=os.getcwd(), debugging=False):
    """Downloads the files provided as multiple url arguments.

    Provide the url for files to be downloaded as strings. Separate the
    files to be downloaded by a comma.

    The function would download the files and save it in the folder
    provided as keyword-argument for download_location. If
    download_location is not provided, then the file would be saved in
    the current working directory. Folder for download_location would be
    created if it doesn't already exist. Do not worry about trailing
    slash at the end for download_location. The code would take carry of
    it for you.

    If the download encounters an error it would alert about it and
    provide the information about the Error Code and Error Reason (if
    received from the server).

    Normal Usage:
    >>> download_file('http://localhost/index.html',
                      'http://localhost/info.php')
    >>> download_file('http://localhost/index.html',
                      'http://localhost/info.php',
                      download_location='/home/aditya/Download/test')
    >>> download_file('http://localhost/index.html',
                      'http://localhost/info.php',
                      download_location='/home/aditya/Download/test/')

    In Debug Mode, files are not downloaded, neither there is any
    attempt to establish the connection with the server. It just prints
    out the filename and its url that would have been attempted to be
    downloaded in Normal Mode.

    By Default, Debug Mode is inactive. In order to activate it, we
    need to supply a keyword-argument as 'debugging=True', like:
    >>> download_file('http://localhost/index.html',
                      'http://localhost/info.php',
                      debugging=True)
    >>> download_file('http://localhost/index.html',
                      'http://localhost/info.php',
                      download_location='/home/aditya/Download/test',
                      debugging=True)

    """
    # Append a trailing slash at the end of download_location if not
    # already present
    if download_location[-1] != '/':
        download_location = download_location + '/'

    # Create the folder for download_location if not already present
    os.makedirs(download_location, exist_ok=True)

    # Other variables
    time_format = '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S'   # '2000-Jan-01 22:10:00'

    # "Request Headers" information for the file to be downloaded
    accept = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
    accept_encoding = 'gzip, deflate'
    accept_language = 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
    connection = 'keep-alive'
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:20.0) \
                  Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0'
    headers = {'Accept': accept,
               'Accept-Encoding': accept_encoding,
               'Accept-Language': accept_language,
               'Connection': connection,
               'User-Agent': user_agent,
               }

    # Loop through all the files to be downloaded
    for url in urls:
        filename = os.path.basename(url)
        if not debugging:
            try:
                request_sent = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
                response_received = urllib.request.urlopen(request_sent)
            except urllib.error.URLError as error_encountered:
                print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(time_format),
                      ':', filename, '- The file could not be downloaded.')
                if hasattr(error_encountered, 'code'):
                    print(' ' * 22, 'Error Code -', error_encountered.code)
                if hasattr(error_encountered, 'reason'):
                    print(' ' * 22, 'Reason -', error_encountered.reason)
            else:
                read_response = response_received.read()
                output_file = download_location + filename
                with open(output_file, 'wb') as downloaded_file:
                    downloaded_file.write(read_response)
                print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(time_format),
                      ':', filename, '- Downloaded successfully.')
        else:
            print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(time_format),
                  ': Debugging :', filename, 'would be downloaded from :\n',
                  ' ' * 21, url)
```

This function works well for downloading PDFs, images and other formats, however its giving trouble with text documents like html files. I suspect the problem has to do something with this line at the end:

```
with open(output_file, 'wb') as downloaded_file:
```

So, I have tried opening it in `wt` mode as well. Have also tried to work with `w` mode only. But this doesn't solve the problem.

The other problem might have been encoding so I have also included the second line as:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

But this still doesn't work. What might be the problem and how do I make it work for both text and binary files?

Example of what doesn't work:

```
>>>download_file("http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html")
```

When I open it in Gedit, it is displayed as:

[image: in gedit]

Similarly when opened in Firefox:

[image: in firefox]

Comment: and what is the problem / error exactly ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: It doesn't give any errors. However, when I open the document in text editor it reports problems about encoding. I would upload the image in a moment..

Comment: @StephaneRolland: Gedit... If I download html files and open them in Firefox, it also displays them as if there is problem with encoding.

Comment: Be sure that downloading is not altering the files, so the problem is elsewhere. Either the source is bad, either your configuration isnt adequate for the content you want to display. Is it possible you files contains eastern languages and that your linux desktop isn't configured for that ?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` comes with '-' between `utf` and `8` (what it seems that you didn't do)?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: The same source works with binary files like pdfs and images - perfectly.. As far as Eastern languages and other stuff - I have downloaded `index.html` of Python Tutorial, this displays perfectly fine when I use Firefox to directly go to that location. However, when I download the same file and open it in Firefox, it is displayed as shown in image above.

Comment: I admit the image is convincing ;-)

Comment: @segfolt: No. changing it to `utf-8` doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are downloading has been sent with gzip encoding -- you can see that if you `zcat index.html`, the downloaded file appears correctly.  In your code, you might want to add something like:

```
if response_received.headers.get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    read_response = zlib.decompress(read_response, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

EDIT:

Well, I can't say why it works on windows (and unfortunately I don't have a Windows box to test it on), but if you post a dump of the response (i.e. convert the response object to a string) that might give some insight. Presumably the server chose not to send with the gzip encoding, but given that this code is pretty explicit about the headers, I'm not sure what would be different.

It's worth mentioning that your headers explicitly specified that gzip and deflate are allowed (see `accept_encoding`).  If you remove that header you shouldn't have to worry about decompressing the response in any case.

Comment: How do you explain that it works perfectly in my computer under Windows 7?

Comment: This works. However, I would also like an explanation as to why does it work in Windows. In the meantime, I would try other permutations and combinations like changing the headers and other stuff.